# UIImageView Mask Layer not coming from corners Until Scroll PageViewController First time

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, layer

I want to achieve this result

[image]

So I need to add mask at bottom but Here What I got

[image]

Code I have tried

```
 private func setupImageCutPath () {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.imgView.frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.width  , y: self.imgView.frame.height - imageCutAwayPart))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.width, y: 0))


        // Multiple tried to check from where masking is comming
        self.maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.maskLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        self.maskLayer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        self.maskLayer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.maskLayer.path = path.cgPath


        self.imgView.layer.mask = self.maskLayer

    }
```

After scroll First time I am getting correct result

I don't understand What I am missing Any Help ?

Comment: The reason you don't get the correct result the first time it's displayed is *probably* because you're calling `setupImageCutPath()` before auto-layout has sized the views. You'll be better off if you create a `UIImageView` subclass and update the mask in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for suggestion I will try this

Comment: @DonMag Yes this works !! , Thanks you so MUCH !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue with

```
    path.move(to: .zero)
    /* THIS HELPLS ME */ path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.imgView.frame.height  -  imageCutAwayPart / 2 ))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.width   , y: self.imgView.frame.height - imageCutAwayPart))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.imgView.frame.width, y: 0))
```

But I don't understand why I need to move `CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.imgView.frame.height  -  imageCutAwayPart / 2 )` instead of  this `CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.imgView.frame.height)`

If any one know this please post as answer I will surely accept the answer

[image]

**EDIT**

There was silly but smart mistake in Storybaord

Mistake was there is UIView which contains Label shown in screenshot. The Part visible is is the UIView I thought it masking is not working properly. Still there is issue that very first time in pageview controller mask is not proper but after scroll one time it is perfect.

**EDIT2 Thanks to @DonMag**

Following is working solution for every case

```
class CutOfImageView:UIImageView {
    let imageCutAwayPart:CGFloat = 80
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.setupImageCutPath()
        self.layer.mask = self.maskLayer

    }

    private func setupImageCutPath () {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0  , y: self.frame.height ))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width   , y: self.frame.height - imageCutAwayPart))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))
        path.close()
        self.maskLayer.path = path.cgPath



    }
}
```