# Custom frame UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

There is an example of two UIView. Tell me, how can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Use mask layer with bezier path, Check code in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779142/uiimageview-mask-layer-not-coming-from-corners-until-scroll-pageviewcontroller-f